# C++ 2d Char array improperly comparing

Tags: c++, char, multidimensional-array

Im creating a connect four, trying to implement the drop feature, add to the lowest row in specific column. heres the init for the board

```
Board::Board()
{
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
            place[i][j] = EMP;  // EMP is a const char = '-'

    cout << "Initalized.\n";
}
```

For some reason this code runs all the way until i = 1, then sets place[1][col] to *
but when i go to display this, it shows the * at the bottom of the array, so place[7][col].

Also this->place and place in the cout at the beginning never give me the output of '-' which it should be.

```
int Board::add(int player, int col)
{
    char piece;
    col--;  // Dealing with array starting at 0, not 1
    (player==1) ? piece = P1: piece = P2;   // Character defining players piece
    int i;

    for (i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
    {

        cout << "this - " << this->place[i][col] << endl;
        cout << "place - " << place[i][col] << endl;
        if(place[i][col] == EMP)
        {
            cout << "Empty looks like " << place[i][col] << "\ti: " << i << endl;
            place[i][col] = piece;
            system("pause");
            return i;
        }else
        {
            cout << "not EMP - " << place[i][col] << endl;
            system("pause");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question is vague "prints all the way to 1 and then does what?" and it is a lot of code for a problem. Can't you at least reduce it a little for some one to be able to assess it decently. Secondly you have got one function pasted multiple times which really confuses the reader. Spend some time explaining your problem well, you will definitely get an answer

Comment: Clearly state what doesn't work and what was expected. You are messing it all too much. I am not even able to figure out what went wrong with your code

Comment: unusual syntax, normally one would write: char piece = (player==1) ? P1:P2;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass a char into your int function, which convert the number into a char variable(gives you garbage). I rewrote the function a little and everything seems to work fine.

```
int Board::add(int player, char col)
{
    char piece;
    int Num;
    Num = atoi(&col);
    cout << Num << endl << endl;
    Num--;  // Dealing with array starting at 0, not 1
    (player==1) ? piece = P1: piece = P2;   // Character defining players piece
    int i;

    for (i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
    {

        cout << "this - " << this->place[i][Num] << endl;
        cout << "place - " << place[i][Num] << endl;
        if(place[i][Num] == EMP)
        {
            cout << "Empty looks like " << place[i][Num] << "\ti: " << i << endl;
            place[i][Num] = piece;
            return i;
        }else
        {
            cout << "not EMP - " << place[i][Num] << endl;
        }
        system("pause");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts:

Don't `delete place`, you never used `new` to obtain the memory.
It's more idiomatic to use the conditional operator like this: `piece = (player==1) ? P1: P2;`

The code to initialize, add, and display pieces pretty much works here: http://codepad.org/QIWHagMk

Can you be more specific with what you're asking or show a much smaller code snippet that demonstrates the problem you're seeing?